# How to pass data to child component?

Tags: angular

I have two components

- FormComponent
- Test1Component

1) `FormComponent` has three buttons Reset, Save and Add

2) `Test1Component` has form fields "First Name" and "Last Name"

3) `FormComponent` uses `ng-content` to load contents of Test1Component

4) `FormComponent` and `Test1Component` both have a `saveForm()` method

When `Save` button is clicked I am trying to get all form values, process them first at `Test1Component.saveForm()` then pass the processed form values to `FormComponent.saveForm()`

The way it is written now, the execution first goes to `FormComponent.saveForm()` emits a `save` event which triggers `Test1Component.saveForm()`

**Now, how do I pass back the processed data from `Test1Component.saveForm()` to `FormComponent.saveForm()`?**

Code is as below

**form.component.ts**

```
import { Component, Input, Output, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-form',
  templateUrl: './form.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./form.component.css']
})
export class FormComponent{
  @Input() headerTitle:string = "Header Title";
  @Input() saveBtnText:string = "Save";
  @Input() resetBtnText:string = "Reset";
  @Input() addBtnText:string = "Add";
  @Output() save:EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();

  constructor(){}

  saveForm(e: any){
    this.save.emit("save");
    console.log("Form save");
  }
}
```

**form.component.html**

```
<div class="panel panel-default fcs-form">
  <div class="panel-header form-header">
        {{headerTitle}}
  </div>


  <div class="panel-body form-body">
    <ng-content select="[form-body]"></ng-content>
  </div>


  <div class="panel-footer text-center form-footer">
        <button class="btn btn-primary">{{resetBtnText}}</button>
      <button class="btn btn-primary" (click)="submitForm()"> {{saveBtnText}} </button>
      <button class="btn btn-primary">{{addBtnText}}</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

**test1.component.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { FormGroup, FormBuilder } from '@angular/forms';
import { FormComponent } from '../form/form.component';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-test1',
  templateUrl: './test1.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./test1.component.css']
})
export class Test1Component{
  complexForm : FormGroup;

  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder){
    this.complexForm = fb.group({
        'firstName' : "",
        'lastName': "",
        'gender' : "Female",
        'hiking' : false,
        'running' : false,
        'swimming' : false
    });
  }

  saveForm(){
    console.log("Child Form save");
  }
}
```

**test1.component.html**

```
<app-form headerTitle="my header" (save)="saveForm($event)">
   <div form-body>
      <p>Fill this form</p>
      <div class="jumbotron">
         <form [formGroup]="complexForm">
            <div class="form-group">
               <label>First Name:</label>
               <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="John" [formControl]="complexForm.controls['firstName']">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
               <label>Last Name</label>
               <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Doe" [formControl]="complexForm.controls['lastName']">
            </div>
         </form>
      </div>
   </div>
</app-form>
```

This is how it looks in the UI

[image]

I also tried @Input, like this

```
@Input() formData;  // In form.component.ts
```

and added [formData] in `test1.component.html`

```
<app-form headerTitle="my header" [formData]="complexForm.value" (save)="saveForm($event)">
```

But in `FormComponent.saveForm()` it gave `undefined`.

Comment: From what I see, data are not processed anywhere and there is no arguments in `saveForm()`. I just don't understand the question.

Comment: @n00dl3 It is currently not there in the code, but that is the way I would like my application to work

Comment: I think if I could get a reference to Test1Component from FromComponent without knowing its name then this could solve my problems

Comment: Only other possible solution I could think of is making `Test1Component.saveForm()` trigger another event, lets call it, `submitForm` and pass the data to a method, like this `FormComponent.submitForm()`. However, Writing another event to just pass data seems ugly.

Comment: @Günter Zöchbauer This question evolves from my previous question

Comment: @CloseVoter, Bolded my question